# comparing listview's and need to display related list items in next page using mysql , php in android

Tags: php, android, sql, localhost

- i had a list view with image and text which is fetching from mysql using php as a scripting language once i clikced on any item the  products related to that item   should be displayed  in the next page ina listview how to do it in php and mysql in android  thanks in advance*

[list of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Qq7.png) [image with the list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA3gt.png)

[list view with related images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFG0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by sending the varaiable from Android to the PHP page.

In my URL I send the variable to PHP by attaching it to the URL like this:

```
"http://192.168.1.12/connect.php?"+orderid;
```

In my PHP program:

```
$orderid=$_POST["orderid"];
$sql="select * from image where orderid='$orderid'";
```